# Mapbox cluster colors according a custom property value

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm working now with mapbox, I'm new in this, what I want to do is set the color of points and clusters according to a custom property 'rains'. For example if the 'rains' property is below 5 the color should be white, if is betweet 5 and 10 should be light blue and so on.I dont have a problem with the invidual points but with the clusters what I want to do is an average of the 'rains' values and then use the same logic.

I'm realy stuck with this, hope someone can help me!

Comment: Which Mapbox SDK are you using?

Comment: Hey! I'm using javascript (Vue.js + Webpack).